# meaning of auto_hold variable in JIL files

Tags: job-scheduling, autosys

In Autosys JIL file, i would like to know the meaning of the variable  **auto_hold**. And when giving  **auto_hold: 1**, what it is meant?

Answer (score 1):

The `auto_hold` attribute denotes whether a job should automatically be put in the `ON_HOLD` status when the box it is in starts. The value of `1` means it should be put `ON_HOLD`, where a value of `0` means it should not.

If the job is not in a box, this attribute is not used.